# npm is installing thousands of files when using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, npm, npm-install

I'm new to using npm and I tried using it in Visual Studio. I used it to install jquery, bootstrap and popper in my project. However it's created 8,520 files in 1,867 folders within the node_modules folder. Is this normal? Is it an error? If so, what am I doing wrong? I'm sorry if this seems like a foolish question, but I've never used it before and it seems like a lot.

This is my package.json file

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "jquery": "3.5.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
        "popper": "1.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably normal, if they have an internal dependencies all of them would be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Each of the packages includes some files. Popper depends on 25 other packages, which are installed too. Each of these 25 packages have their own dependencies which are installed, and so on and so forth. So, no you are probably not doing anything wrong ...

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. My confidence in it is restored.